# altair heatmap: how to apply axis labels wrap, without losing meaning in values and cell values?

Tags: altair, vega-lite

I have some long label in axis (see the example below). [Here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlANzgUwO4tJKAFzigFcJSBnAdTgBNCALFAZgAY2AacaYsiygAlMiRoVYcAvpO50AhoTl4QUOQFtMKEPMUBaOmACcAVgDsMQ5jaZMAI2PHMclgCYALGzcw3bgBxfjFlNjXxAZEDU5ACcAay0ozDBxbkwoSDoSJFQeABsIKOV4TBy6LTQQbhzMBFTS7OJCKq0w7kowOSbsqLkoGpQAbRAAYhhzWxgYCuG2X3YANlsQAF1wwgBPAAdNZBAAR1IehoU4NE1wgA9CrBKtHIB9S9b88Wyim52oKYgNrTUSL6idEwBR2cjatUyLRADU6IAACgkMklMHQAAQ5OS2YpTdZbLRQCB-VQ5KFrK7FOoge5kp5RF6gN6Uz7cb6-f4swHArRgsAQ3pQmHbEAAFSipEw6Mx2O4uKFBKJHTC4UYIgQYlYcy4IGw9CYGq1ABI2irIloxIQNpRkAB6a2nBByAB0CDgTFItkdcAg1uNmEiduqcl0OVdmDtxkdLkdbEdACtKNApjowZhCJRlMn9EYzBYrDZ7I5nO5PN4-AEgiEBqBPsgAIzcS7ILVkpvccrIFgsQymObGSoPfEQVHJqbUwfDhRKGTVlAuBsoZsoWssNxtpcuNjBfuNlRDkf9lsgABi+UwlEInGHiXo5Col9sUQgcjRVTkk2nKlY89bIBby7ma7IKYy6rlSA4fHuk6jnch4ngk56XqQUAxAS2CfB+NagY2IHcC2WrthutYuIY25aHBZ4XleYA3gI96Ps+6JOJMB7jiOGEoH2IDYSuuFLjxIDtsEtbdqROzkQhVE0XeqIPk+L5MdBsGnhJQLUXQt6UHRcmMW+LQzsgAFcXxoF-iwhntnMHicfcO7iZRqlSZpMn0fJuksWJymUUhKEQGhemfkB37-rxP7tq4Pa+KJx6eYhyGocyYGHgSE6KP5NaRUZdZmSFOECbOxhuKYLBRXZsU+X57nRfB9nXuptHOdpr7vpw+kkZlwW-nx5lLsYtZsG1NlkTFqLefFilDdVZVjZIKySEAA) in the vega editor.

[image]

If I apply wrap

```
df['l_x'] = df['l_x'].apply(wrap, args=[10])
df['l_y'] = df['l_y'].apply(wrap, args=[10])
```

it works for the labels, but the colors in my graph lose meaning (look at the new 1️⃣ white cells and 2️⃣ generally to the new colors of cells) and the cell labels disappear, probably because the output lists break everything. [Here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlANzgUwO4tJKAFzigFcJSBnAdTgBNCALFAZgAY2AacaYsiygAlMiRoVYcAvpO50AhoTl4QUOQFtMKEPMUBaMGAAshuQEYwAJjYWAnCcMA2FgFYARqdNsb71wA5nzgDsmE4gMiBqcgBOANZaUZhg4tyYUJB0JEioPAA2EFHK8Jg5dFpoINw5mAippdnEhFVaYdyUYHJN2VFyUDUoANogAMQwgTCuMDAVw2y+7A6uIAC64YQAngAOmsggAI6kPQ0KcGia4QAehVglWjkA+pet+eLZRTc7UNMQG1pqJF9ROiYAo7ORtWqZFogBqdEAABQSGSSmDoAAIcnJXMVpustlooBA-qoclC1ldinUQPcyU8oi9QG9KZ9uN9fv8WYDgVowWAIb0oTDtiAACpRUiYdGY7HcXFCglEjphcKMEQIMSsBxcEDYehMDVagAkbRVkS0YkIG0oyAA9NbTgg5AA6BBwJikVyOuAQa3GzCRO3VOS6HKuzB25yOiyOtiOgBWlGg0x0YMwhEoymT+iMJnMVls9icbg8Xh8-iCIRYA1An2Qpm4l2QWrJje45WQLBYNkCDmclQeAxUEFRyeWfebgwJw4UShWnGrKAs9ZQTZQphYhlbq6sgV7VP7yAnQ5HSzHA4AYvlMJRCNxZIl6OQqLeQK4ohA5GiqnIprP5+2ly2IDNmuDibsggRrhue4NoeU6KKOe7jiAF4JNez6kFAMQEtgny-ioKBQQ2kHcM2WptlYpi2H2MHIZeaFJvedCPpQz6vu+n6YN+CHUgOk7HjIf67kR64kauIkgG2O6mF21HnnRN4MWAD4CKxb4fuinE-qeB60ahCl3kpTEqdMbHqV+P4CfhyCgSAwlQcBLA2W2DiGGwu73DRKFXvp2iMcxqnsRpXEnohcl6ehmHYbhlk1oEAEgaJgFtiwFjdr4sk6V59HcBhWEQDh3F3EhfHTssMUoOltliTZDlQeRziGIELAZYMWU+blUWFUhbXPkChn+SZakccF5XIDY8WOYlCUSauzieON0Fhd5EV5QVIU8Zl8krZ1KwrJIQA) in the vega editor.
How to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Please provide example code for the issue with the color text, it seems like the second link doesn't recreate your issue in the second image?

Comment: hi @joelostblom and thank you. I have edited the text and uploaded a right image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have first applied python wrap and then a search and replace in my fields

```py
wrap=10
df['l_x'] = df['l_x'].str.wrap(wrap)
df['l_y'] = df['l_y'].str.wrap(wrap)
df['l_x'] = df['l_x'].str.replace('\n', '@')
df['l_y'] = df['l_y'].str.replace('\n', '@')
```

Then I have set for x and y

```py
axis=alt.Axis(labelExpr="split(datum.Label,'@')")
```

And now [it works](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlANzgUwO4tJKAFzigFcJSBnAdTgBNCALFAZgAY2AacaYsiygAlMiRoVYcAvpO4AbAIYBPTACcUAbVABbeSoDWKECsxhx3TFEh0SSVD1kQ1d+Jll1DaEHMwIL7u8SEspiGIDIglGDywXhG8lC+GiAAxDAA7DAARjAwXilsABzsAGyZIAC64YSKAA4hyCAAjqTxgfLEaCHhAB6x8t1wlLEKma4AggkxyFwgI64Aot01ThE1snCEABR07aRaAHRzspwA5AACJwCUYdwuboayAPq93JSO4s5Y9w1QeRA1hi0JD+KjoqkM8kifhsNxAgSmIAACsZrKZMHQAARHPLVOqGKAQIFQaKwxR9AZDOxHCYIKYzI6LZaGShrDbbXYHI6nC7XcJ3fyzR5k17vWL8-F-AENIkgsErSFgaEJWHw+ogAAqKlImCx8lGshxtTVBKJJOkMm0ugMASNhkImG6ZhA0UQvwaiqI4O4mUhrhIaqBdDoMVuvAAynAAF71ACMbHCFisMLskAcTnw0GsxGgsTQ0W1hmwjA2IW49soHxA7MIe32aAxAD4MQAmACsABYCs2WPs0q3edw87ICw1MgowAYqg6PqBxQ1PKGVDpK-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-NjKAfSAR6ORzm3E99MbNsZ5MNDTkOENDsPwwISMo2jWIY+uVMU7dNygG6R2c29PNa8TfYxvtwtgxDdOS3QCOUDLqPo5jl1CoYosmyYUuI2cyNW-LNts8gROa8g3ME37FnE8U7ZsBrTz-Q74sw07ZvS67svW4rV0i8b0cM0zEAs6rD1pHjjk+7zIDbSwQXFAUhtR9DGfM1xKcAzdhB3ZwasoBXvsFwH-vF4FHZpLj3722n1eM7XtvU8PMdw3HLtu3LwSey3D1Cx3QcgHhnc937rZxivEdD7T6ej1ndd26nh8j5n2eSJUkhAA). Thank you [Casey Haber](https://vega-js.slack.com/archives/C4R371X41/p1681141547222289?thread_ts=1681133181.822619&cid=C4R371X41).

[image]